# Auto height paper Reportlab Python (case study about ribbon paper for printing shopping receipts)

Tags: python, django, reportlab

How to make `height` measurements automatically based on content (shopping lists and prices) that will be printed on ribbon paper with a `width` of `110mm` (currently I use that size paper to print - using thermal printer - shopping receipts).

The following is a sample code snippet that I have:

```py
class TOPDFBarcodeThermal(TOPDF):
    width = 110 * mm
    limit = 110 * mm # auto height in here


    def set_pdf(self):
        self.pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(
            self.response,
            title=self.title,
            rightMargin=0,
            leftMargin=0,
            topMargin=0,
            bottomMargin=0,
            pagesize=(self.width, self.limit)
        )
```

On the ribbon paper, I want to make it have a dynamic height that matches the list of items purchased.

Are there other easier ways or what?

Thank you

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? I am trying to achieve basically the same thing but so far haven't had any luck.